# collapse button : working offline with bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a problem with bootstrap 3.
I wanted to make a responsive navbar, but when i make the page smaller, and the button is shown, unfortunatly it doesn't react to the click event, though  i added the bootstrap.js and jquery.js

Here is the code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" th:fragment="gennav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/servicemed/" th:href="@{/}"><b>Service Medicale</b></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/servicemed/" th:href="@{/}"><span class="fa fa-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/servicemed/" th:href="@{/}"><span class="fa fa-rocket"></span> Not</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/servicemed/" th:href="@{/}"><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

any idea why it's not working? do i need another js file to make it happen ?

PS : do not mind the "th:*" tags, i'm using thymeleaf

**EDIT:**

The code above work normally when i include the jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js files with links (internet needed) but when i download them and try to add them locally (offline), the button doesn't work , any ideas why ?

Comment: Looks ok on bootply http://www.bootply.com/zzi8Gmd9Ya

Comment: then what's the problem ? i already had included jquery.js and bootstrap.min.js in my html file, and i had tested it on jsfiddle and it worked too, but when i run it on glassfish using intellij (i'm making a web app with spring mvc 4 and hibernate ...), the button just doesn't react to the click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Please see here](http://jsbin.com/ropat/1/edit) your html code is fine make sure that you have in header reference to those 2 scripts:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i already had included jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js in my html file, and i had tested it on jsfiddle and it worked too, but when i run it on glassfish using intellij (i'm making a web app with spring mvc 4 and hibernate ...), the button just doesn't react to the click

Comment: @Aissasa please check order jQuery has to be before bootstrap

Comment: i found the problem, when i include an offline version of the js files (which is a necessity for the purpuse of the app i'm working on) it doesn't work, but when i use the online versions (with the lines above) it works, so my question now: is there a difference between the two approches and how make it work locally (offline), and thank you :)

Comment: Just copy those scripts to your local drive and add the local reference

Comment: that's what i did but it's not working for me, i don't understand why

Comment: can you please add to your question page header tag ?